# How to choose K point from this convergence value

Tags: quantum-espresso

[image][image]

My System is 2H MoS2 unit cell with vacuum. Energy is varied in zig zag form. How can predict the k points from this convergence.

Comment: There is no absolute answer to what constitutes a converged value, it depends on what you are interested in. For example, if you need to resolve physics that occurs on a 10 meV scale, then you could go with $6\times6\times1$, but if you are interested in physics that occurs on a 1 meV scale, then you probably need to use something more like $16\times16\times1$ or finer. Also, if you are interested in other quantities that are not the total energy, they may converge at slightly different rates, for example energy differences tend to converge more easily.

Comment: I need to calculate the band structure in electronic properties of 2H MoS2 (Vacuum). Which grid either odd or even have to choose based on the convergence result.

Comment: Again, it depends on how finely you need to resolve the band structure (e.g. do you need the band gap within 10 meV or 1 meV?). Also, a band structure calculation is computationally inexpensive, so I would suggest that you directly calculate the band structure with a few different $\mathbf{k}$-point grids, and use that (rather than the total energy calculations you have now) to decide on your converged grid.

Comment: Sir, I use 12*12*1 grid. Along k path i select 150 for band gap calculation.Few curvature cut at 1.8(y axis). Below 1.8 maximum curvature but after that minimum number of curvature. How to rectify this. I added image.

Comment: Is your KPOINTS are gamma centred or Monkhorst? As your lattice is hex hence try gamma centred with odd KPOINTS but even though you have tightened your tolerance too much.

Comment: I will choose 15*15*1 as k grid.Yes its hexagonal and gamma centered. Sir, (tolerence) which have to increase or decrease.Please Clarify. I added input file. What about nbnd - how to choose the nbnd value.Is it affect accuracy.

Comment: While you will be notified of all comments as the post author, you will need to ping the user you want to address for them to get a notification. For example, I will ping @ProfM.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117642/quantum-espresso   use this chatroom for further discussion

Comment: @pranavkumar Thanks for pointing them to chat! I actually just added a [Meta post](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267/preserving-comments-and-chat-integration) about how users can help with the process of preserving comments/moving longer discussions to chat.